# Erro ao passar index de um array

Tags: php, array, mvc

Boa noite.

Acredito que meu problema seja simples, porém não encontrei nada que o sanasse.

Estou fazendo um CRUD em PHP, utilizando MVC, para aprender como a linguagem funciona. Acontece que o banco de dados MySql trabalha com data no formato yyy-mm-dd e a data que o usuário passa é dd/mm/yyyy. Até ai tudo bem, o problema é que quando vou pegar o campo "data" no meu array, é retornado um erro dizendo que o index não existe. Seguem prints com explicação abaixo.

[image: Formulário HTML, onde consta o campo "cliente['data_nasc_cliente']" e chama a função insere.]

[image: Função insere, onde o erro é disparado.]

[image: Erro que me é apresentado.]

Imagem 1: Formulário HTML, onde consta o campo "cliente['data_nasc_cliente']" e chama a função insere.

Imagem 2: Função insere, onde o erro é disparado.

Imagem 3: Erro que me é apresentado.

Answer (score 0):

Você está a querer acessar um método que não estão disponível para a variável: `$_cliente['data_nasc_cliente']`.

veja:

```
$_cliente['data_nasc_cliente']->format('y-m-d');
```

Para formatar uma data você primeiro precisa construir um objeto data:

```
$data = new DateTime($_cliente['data_nasc_cliente']) ;
$_cliente['data_nasc_cliente'] =  $data->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: Faz sentido, porém ainda assim o problema persiste. Note que o erro é "Undefined index".